# Using Parseval's theorem

Tags: fourier-series

I'm given that the function $f(x)$ is smooth and $2\pi$ periodic on $-\pi \le x \le \pi$.

I want to use Parseval's theorem to find: $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f'(x)^2} dx$$

In terms of $$||f|| = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)^2}dx = \frac{a_0^2}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2)$$

My attempt:

Let $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n cos(nx)+ b_n sin(nx)}$

Then differentiating:

$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{cos(nx)(nb_n)+sin(nx)(-na_n)}$

Applying Parseval's theorem for the first integral yields:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(nb_n)^2}+(na_n)^2$

How do I express this in terms of $||f||$?